# How can I automatically delete and create a Lambda function in a different region when updating the provider in a Terraform module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm managing AWS resources with Terraform, including a scenario where Lambda functions and CloudWatch alarms are deployed. My setup is defined with a default AWS provider for `us-west-2` and aliases for `us-east-1` and `us-east-2`. Deploying a Lambda module in the default region works as intended. However, when I attempt to redeploy the same Lambda module to a different region by specifying a provider alias, Terraform treats it as a new resource creation instead of an update or move.

Here's a simplified version of my provider configuration in `root/providers.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "useast1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "useast2"
  region = "us-east-2"
}
```

And my module invocation looks like this:

```
module "mylambdamodulename" {
  source    = "./modules/lambda"
}
```

For example, changing to

```
module "mylambdamodulename" {
  source    = "./modules/lambda"
  providers = { aws = aws.useast2 }
}
```

Creates a new one in useast2 but doesn't destroy the old one in the default region.

Changing the module's name based on the region (e.g., appending _useast2 to the module name) forces Terraform to recognize it as a distinct resource, but this approach is prone to human error and could lead to inconsistencies.

Is there a Terraform-native way to ensure that changing the target deployment region of a module will lead Terraform to treat it as the same resource undergoing an update or relocation, rather than creating a new instance? I'm looking for a solution that would minimize manual naming conventions and potential discrepancies in our infrastructure management process.

This is configured to run a pipeline in github, so manual intervention each time is out of the picture.

Comment: Can you elaborate of why moving from the default region is needed? In other words, why would you want to move the function retroactively? You could create two Lambda functions immediately and then remove the one from the default region in the subsequent commit.

Comment: @MarkoE Sometimes, we need to move functions to a new region. I guess I'm more so concerned if a team member changes the providers thinking it will delete-recreate then we suddenly have an issue with stuff being "out of sync"

Comment: In that case, I guess using [moved](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax) block makes the most sense.